# COMO RESOLVER? not found class in C:\wamp64\www\controllers\ControllerEvents.php

Tags: php

Não consigo resolver esse erro. Já tentei use/include/require...

Ao abrir http://localhost/controllers/ControllerEvents.php
deveria mostrar dois eventos criados no banco de dados. Mas aparece o erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Classes\ClassEvents' not found in C:\wamp64\www\controllers\ControllerEvents.php on line 3

> Error: Class 'Classes\ClassEvents' not found in C:\wamp64\www\controllers\ControllerEvents.php on line 3

File -> index.php

```
<?php
include ("./config/config.php");
require "./class/ClassTeste.php";
require "./model/ModelConect.php";

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Agendamento</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo DIRPAGE.'lib/css/stylecalendar.css'; ?>">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo DIRPAGE.'lib/js/FullCalendar/main.min.css'; ?>">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="calendar"></div>
<script src="<?php echo DIRPAGE.'lib/js/FullCalendar/main.min.js'; ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo DIRPAGE.'lib/js/javascript.js'; ?>"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

File -> ControllerEvents.php

```
<?php 
include ("../config/config.php"); 
$objEvents=new \Classes\ClassEvents();
var_dump($objEvents->getEvents());
```

File -> ModelConect.php

```
<?php
namespace Models;

 abstract class ModelConect
{
    protected function conectDB()
    {
        try{
            $con=new \PDO("mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".DB."",USER,PASS);
            return $con;
        }catch (\PDOException $erro){
            return $erro->getMessage();
}
}
}
```

File -> config.php

```
<?php
#Caminhos absolutos
$dirInt="";
define('DIRPAGE',"http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/{$dirInt}");
$bar=(substr($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],-1)=='/')?"":"/";
define('DIRREQ',"{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}{$bar}{$dirInt}");

#Banco de Dados
define('HOST','localhost');
define('DB','sistema');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');

#Incluir arquivos
include(DIRREQ.'lib/vendor/autoload.php');
```

File-> ClassEvents.php

```
<?php
namespace Classes;

use Models\ModelConect;

class ClassEvents extends ModelConect
{
#Trazer os dados de eventos do banco
public function getEvents()
{
   $b=$this->conectDB()->prepare("select * from events");
   $b->execute();
   $f=$b->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return $f;
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Opa!

Ele tá buscando Classes/ClassEvents dentro da pasta controllers.

O diretório Classes está mesmo dentro de controllers?

Se não talvez você deva usar ./Classes/ClassEvents

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: O diretório Classes não está dentro de controllers.
Nada feito, ainda não resolveu...